# What does "some" refer to in the context?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, british-english, pronouns

In this article from  [The Economist](https://www.economist.com/britain/2023/01/26/britain-is-beginning-to-protect-its-1970s-leisure-centres) it says:

> - *As Britons took to holidaying in the actual Mediterranean, some began to decline; austerity and covid-19 finished them off.*

The short line " some began to decline" reads as incomplete. Did it omit anything? What is "some" referring to? The elderly?

Comment: In isolation it means that some Britons began to decline and were then finished off.  It doesn't make a whole lot of sense, or is much less elegant than The Economist usually manages.  I suspect that the preceding sentence, or two, might be necessary to parse this one.

Comment: I'm unable to read the whole article, but it's about leisure centres in the UK, so it is presumably some of those which began to decline.

Comment: Given that the OP presumably had the entire article available, as did @michael harvey, one wonders hoe

Comment: …why the op asks at the expense of the regulars.

Answer (score 4):

The relevant section of the article (in *The Economist* dated 28 January 2023) is below. 'Some' refers to 'The indoor leisure centres of the 1970s and 1980s'.

> **The indoor leisure centres of the 1970s and 1980s** were about family and fun.
>
> **Their** pools were curvy and fringed with trees. You walked into the
> water via gently sloping beaches; **the leisure centres’** architects had
> discovered that many Britons could barely swim. **They** had wave machines
> and waterslides, **and some** served alcohol. **Their** designers aimed to
> bring the Mediterranean to ordinary Britons. As Britons took to
> holidaying in the actual Mediterranean, **some** began to decline;
> austerity and covid-19 finished **them** off.